# Can you set an Integer to be null in C# 2.0?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

Can you set an Integer to be null in C# 2.0?

Comment: why not use
code:
int? yourint;

Comment: You can do this in any kind of C# 2.0 program, not just in ASP.NET

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming you are using c# 2.0 & .net framework 2.0 onwards.

Use nullable types for that.
e.g. `int? myValue = null`;
or
`Nullable<int> myOtherValue = null;`

EDIT: See an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: what about inside a class declaration

Comment: MyClass(int? myInt, string someString){

}

Comment: @littleMan: you mean a constructor?  `MyClass(int? myInt, string someString) {}`

Comment: Yeah can you and do you use them in constructors

Comment: @littleMan: Yes.  Try it out.